# How to prevent Ocp-Apim-Trace: true and ocp-apim-trace-location in production?

Tags: azure-api-management

I underestand that when a request includes `Ocp-Apim-Trace: true` like below:

```
GET /api/v1/BotConfig HTTP/1.1
Host: xyz.azure-api.net
Cache-Control: no-cache
Ocp-Apim-Trace: true
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
```

The API Management adds ocp-apim-trace-location header:

```
ocp-apim-trace-location: https://womewhere.blob.core.windows.net/apiinspectorcontainer/Hin6_SGFT-some-parameters
```

This is obviously a security probelm and I am sure I am missing a point.

What is the mechanism to enable `ocp-apim-trace-location` for API Management developers, but make sure it is disabled for public service consumers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trace location (*ocp-apim-trace-location* in response header) is available only for admin accounts. For non-admin accounts or when there is no subscription key the traces aren't collected.

Comment: Thank you for help. Do you know if this information is covered in the Documentation?